# select option always selected and hidden

Tags: vue.js

I would like this behaviour:

- Previous years option is not available

When selecting the year in "select"

- I would like "Previous years" to be shown again
- and the {{year}} displays the year (this is OK)

  ```
      <span>{{year}}</span>
      <select @change="onYearSelect($event)">
          <option selected hidden>Previous years</option>
          <option v-for="year in years" :value="year" :key="year">{{year}}</option>
      </select>
  ```

  methods:{
      onYearSelect(event) {
          this.year=event.target.value
      },
  }

It seems simple but I don't manage to get it :)

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want something like this:

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: "#elm",
  data: {
    year: null,
    years: [2014, 2015, 2016, 2017, 2018, 2019]
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.min.js"></script>

<div id="elm">
  <span>{{year}}</span>
  <select v-model="year">

    <option :value="null" disabled hidden>Previous years</option>
    <option v-for="year in years" :value="year" :key="year">{{year}}</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Just set give the `Previous years` option a `disabled` tag: `<option disabled>Previous years</option>`.

Also, you don't need `@change`, just use `v-model="year"`, check [Form Input Bindings](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Select) documentation

Comment: Thanks, actually I already have this but I would like "previous years" to be always selected, even after we select solmething else...

Comment: @gertrude , I updated my answer, is that what you need to achieve?

Comment: Thanks, not excatly but this was a good tip also :D i should have put all my code, sorry.
what I need to achieve is that each time we select a year, the combobox (<select>) is set to "previous years" while the <span>{{year}}</span> is actually set.